# New block scope for selection and iteration statement

Tags: c

In C99 for iteration statements and selection statements there are new block scopes and I understand that the `if`, `while`, etc. itself are block as their sub statement also without `{ }`.

C11 Specification:

6.8.4:

> A selection statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the
>   scope of its enclosing block. Each associated substatement is also a
>   block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the selection
>   statement.

6.8.5

> An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of
>   the scope of its enclosing block. The loop body is also a block whose
>   scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement.

But If I do:

```
if( (int a = 10) == 10 ) // error: expected expression before '==' token
   int j = 10; // error: expected expression before 'int'
```

GCC give me errors.

How can I verify that C99 new rule?

Can anyone give me some working examples?

Comment: Which rule specifically is that?

Comment: @2501, I edited the question with specification rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is simply not allowed by syntax of C language. N1570 §6.8.4/p1:

> Syntax
>    selection-statement:
>     if ( expression ) statement

Both *expression* and *statement* are not considered as declaration (*declaration expression* to best strict). The best what you can do is to put declaration inside `{}` brackets, like:

```
int a = 10;
if (a == 10) {
    int j = 10;
}
```

The only case allowed by standard (and introduced by C99 indeed) is to place declaration instead of initializing expression in `for` loop:

```
for (int a = 0, b = 0; a + b < 20; a++, b++) {
    int j = 10;
}
```

Reference for that is §6.8.5/p1 (see forth form):

> Syntax
>    iteration-statement:
>     while ( expression ) statement
>     do statement while ( expression ) ;
>     for ( expression<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ) statement
>     for ( declaration expression<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ) statement

The real question here is what is the purpose of separate scope for `if` statement (as of §6.8.4/p5) if you can't take use of it with declaration expression. You see that is only possible with `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I read an article of Straustrup where he discussed the problem of integration of C and C++. As we can see it seems the probem is unresolved. Even statement definitions differ fundamentally.
In C the controlling expression of if statement may be ony an expression. Thus for example this statement

```
if ( const char *p = std::strchr( "Hello", 'H' ) ) { /*...*/ }
```

is valid in C++ but the similar statement

```
if ( char *p = strchr( "Hello", 'H' ) ) { /*...*/ }
```

is not vaid in C.

But in any case your if statement neither vaid in C++ nor in C.:)

```
if( (int a = 10) == 10 )
```

There can be either an expression or declaration. From the C++ Standard

```
condition:

expression
attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer-clause
attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator braced-init-list
```