# lone declaration in if statement?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration

I did not understand why this works:

```
if(1)
{
    int i;
}
```

and this not:

```
if(1) 
    int i;
```

> error: expected expression before int

If you could supply some standard reference.

Comment: Please take the time to describe your problem clearly. What behaviour are you observing? People can guess but it is better if you explicitly describe what you did and what you observed.

Comment: it does work, "i" just goes out of scope immediately in both examples, where in the first one you can use "i" within the control structure if you wanted to.  In the second one you can't (in c++)

Comment: @KerrekSB Can reproduce: https://ideone.com/xJtJLe

Comment: I got error : `expected expression before int`

Comment: How about you put that into the question? Include your compiler details.

Comment: @2501: Well, the goalposts have been moving...

Comment: @2501 Different results: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b150d1e134c013b9

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is just a simple warning which means it works for you.

Comment: @2501 I wanted just to see if it is the same thing for C++ language that's why I included it but my main purpose is C. If possible you can include C++ behavior.

Comment: 4 votes, for closing as unclear what you're asking?! The only valid close reason used to be *can no longer be reproduced*, but OP edited the question withing 3 minutes. This is bandwagon downvoting... All those close reasons are invalid and should be removed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Really?!: `g++ -std=` **c++14** `-O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out;`

Comment: Hmm 3 answers address the declaration aspect `int i;`, but to me its the unfulfilled `if(1) ...` that is the problem as hinted by "error: expected expression before int".

Comment: @2501 That's why one shouldn't tag c questions with the c++ tag originally.

Comment: @chux-- your point is that declarations are not expressions, so the syntax of the `if` statement is incomplete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New block scope for selection and iteration statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337616/new-block-scope-for-selection-and-iteration-statement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, declarations can only occur as part of a *compound-statement*, not as part of any of the other kinds of *statement* (see C11 6.8 and 6.8.2).

Comment: (I'm not entirely sure where the global structure of a C program is specified; obviously declarations can also appear at file scope. But I think those aren't statements.)

Comment: So declarations are not considered as statement neither as expression they are just declaration right ?

Comment: Well, they are *part* of a *compound-statement*, but they are not a statement on their own, right. And they can also appear at file scope and in the *clause-I* of a `for` statement.

Comment: I think that's the main reason.

Answer (score 3):

Declaration must be a part of a block-item<sup>1</sup>.

The block-item-list contains a block-item<sup>2</sup>.

And the block-item-list can only be inside brackets, as part of a compound-statement<sup>3</sup>.

This is different in C++, as a declaration-statement is included in statement (the former allows, via a block-statement, defining variables).

---

(Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.8.2 Compound statement 1)

<sup>1</sup> 
block-item:
    declaration

<sup>2</sup>
block-item-list:
    block-item
    block-item-list block-item

<sup>3</sup>
compound-statement:
    { block-item-list opt }

Comment: Expression statement is considered as a statement;

Comment: @Sabrina Yes that is correct. It also isn't a declaration, so it doesn't allow variable definition.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to C grammar. Specifically, the `if` statement is defined as:

> if ( *expression* ) *statement*

According to C11 6.8 *Statements and blocks*, the statement is one of:

> *labeled-statement
> compound-statement
> expression-statement
> selection-statement
> iteration-statement
> jump-statement*

The declaration can only directly appear in either compound-statement (i.e. delimeted by `{ ... }`) or as a special case as first expression in `for` iteration-statement.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from [section 6.8.2p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.2p1) which covers the `{ ... }`-style example, a *declaration* is permitted within a *compound-statement*.

[Section 6.8.4p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4), however, which covers the syntax for selection statements (i.e. `if (...) ...`) doesn't explicitly permit any *declaration*s. In addition, this notation requires an *expression*, as hinted by the error message, "expected *expression* ..."

Answer (score 0):

The first code example declares an int visible only inside an otherwise empty scope ... hard to see the utility!  The second apparently attempts to conditionally? declare an int visible in the enclosing (function?) scope.  Hard to imagine the utility of such a conditional declaration ... would it require run-time re-compilation?

Comment: Not that hard to image: `if(1) int x = FunctionReturningInt();`

Comment: You are indeed confused about *function scope*; the only kind of identifier that can have that is a *label* (i.e. the identifiers you use in conjunction with `goto`). You probably intended to use the term *block scope*... By the way, the question requests a standard reference... Do you think this response correctly answers the question? Or is it just commentary on the question which should be provided as a comment?